# Pyinstaller Permission OSError Permission Denied

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am attempting to create an exe of a computer vision program, but I am running into a permission error.

Command through anaconda prompt (run as administrator):

```
pyinstaller -F --name "Computer Vision" --add-data "model.xml;_model2_.hdf5" C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\project\project_CV.spec
```

When the exe builds successfully and is run I have the following error when referencing my model.xml and model2.hdf5 files. Within my python code the files are referenced to the relative path as follows according to the pyinstaller documentation:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

However, when I run the exe the files are found, but they can't be accessed due to permission error:

```
OSError: Unable to open file, errno = 13, error message = permission denied
```

I am on a Windows device running python 3.6 and pyinstaller 3.4, I have consulted the other stack overflow questions on this topic, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Your add data syntax is wrong. If you want to add multiple files: `pyinstaller  --add-data "model.xml;." --add-data "_model2_.hdf5;." script.py`

Comment: This solution is correct, tested, and working as a console input.

Following the same convention I have made it work through spec as well with the following:

datas=[('model.xml','.'),('model2_.hdf5','.')]

Answer (score 0):

The [`add-data`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) syntax is like below:

`--add-data "<path to file or files>;<path on target>"`. So if you want to add multiple files with different names you need to provide them individually.

So the correct format for your question is:

```
pyinstaller -F --name "Computer Vision" --add-data "model.xml;." --add-data "_model2_.hdf5;." <your_script_name>.py
```

Also, remember that when you use `*.spec` any argument would be ignored so you need to edit your spec file manually or use arguments on your script.